# What exactly is Boost?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm a relatively new player.  I received a message in my Clash of Clans inbox that said this:

```
Boost anything for only one gem!  Event lasts until January 7th.
```

What is **Boost**?  I cannot find a *Boost* option on any of my structures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boosting is when you spend gems on any structure that creates something(spell factory, gold mine, elixor collector, dark elixor drill, dark barracks, and [normal] barracks)  to either reduce time building or double resources made.

For example: if you click on any gold drill in your base, you will have the option to boost for 1 day, which doubles production, for 1 gem.   Normal cost of boost for gold mines is 11gems.

Comment: I don't have the option to boost my gold collectors, elixir collectors, or barracks.  Is there a level requirement?

Comment: Oh, yes sorry.   You must be at least level 5 to boost.

Comment: That does seem to agree with what I'm seeing--the structure needs to be level 5+ to be boostable.

Comment: The normal barracks can be boosted at level 4.  Perhaps it was 5 for gold and elixirs.

Answer (score 2):

The "boost" in Clash of Clans means that, for example, boosting a gold mine would make the mine produce gold faster. The "boost" is the green light circling resource collectors that you might see when you visit other players. Basically, it just boosts your resource collectors. Hope I could help! :)